# Unable to validate date format in shell script

Tags: linux, shell-script

I am trying to give a user 3 chances to type in correct date format which is mm/dd/yy.

If all the 3 times he puts in wrong date format the code will display "Invalid date" and if once out of the 3 chances he enters correct format the message "Correct Date" should be displayed.

But every time i run the below code its doesn't give the desired output.  Please let me know what am i doing wrong ??

```
a=0
while [ $a -lt 3 ]
do
    echo -n "enter the date :"
    read date
    [[ $date =~  ([0-9][0-9])/([0-9][0-9])/([0-9]) ]] || { printf "Invalid date\n"; }
    (( a++ )) 
done
    [[ "$date" = "([0-9][0-9])/([0-9][0-9])/([0-9])" ]] || { printf "correct date\n"; }

exit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seems to work (though it could be tidied some more), the error you had was that it always looped even if he entered date in the correct format:

```
#!/bin/bash
a=0
while [ $a -lt 3 ]
do
    echo -n "enter the date :"
    read date
    [[ $date =~  ([0-9][0-9])/([0-9][0-9])/([0-9]) ]] && break
    printf "Invalid date\n"; 
    (( a++ )) 
done
[[ $date =~ ([0-9][0-9])/([0-9][0-9])/([0-9]) ]] && { printf "correct date\n"; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues with the script above:

1. The regex you're matching the string can be a bit more specific. This is not an issue, actually, but you know you can't rely on the user so you should validate that date correctly. Note that you don't need the parenthesis either. So a better one could be:

   ```
   ^[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]$
   ```
2. You continue on the loop even if the user has entered a valid date. You should exit the loop if the user has succeeded. I haven't tried this but it should work:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   validdate=0
   a=0
   while [ $a -lt 3 ] && [ ! $validdate ]
   do
       echo -n "enter the date :"
       read date
       [[ $date =~ ^[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]$ ]] && validdate=1
       if [ ! $validdate ];
       then
           printf "Invalid date\n"; 
           (( a++ )) 
       fi
   done

   if [ ! $validdate ]
   then
      echo "3 wrong attempts"
   else
      echo "Date ok!"
   fi
   ```

Comment: thanks, could you please explain little more what does '^' and $ mean in the above eg

Comment: The `^` symbolizes the beggining of a string, while `$` is the end of the string in the regexp world. What you assure this way is that the user won't enter `11/22/33a`, for example, because that would match as correct in your first attempt. However, if you delimite the string, even entering the final `a`, it won't match.